# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined React js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I am Working on React app. i am using Header.js Component in child componnet of other component.
  when i click on link it is not redirect to other component it is displayed following Error Message.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Version Using "react": "^16.12.0",  "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",

Searced on lot of from stack overflow but no one is working.Please Help

Header.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { history } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
//import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";--> Not Working

class Header extends React.Component {    

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        Search: '',
        guid:'',
        activeOption: 0,
        filteredOptions: [],
        showOptions: false,
        userInput: ''
    }
    this.onChangeSearch = this.onChangeSearch.bind(this);
    this.routeChange = this.routeChange.bind(this);
    this.Redirect = this.Redirect.bind(this);
}

onChangeSearch= (e) => {
    this.setState({ Search: e.target.value })       

     const obj = {
        User_Guiid:guid,
        Search:this.state.Search
     }
     if(this.state.Search!="")
     axios.post('http://localhost:xxxx/Api/Authenticate/Searchuser', obj }).then(response => {
        // console.log(response.data)  
         if(response.status=="200")
         {
            this.setState({
                filteredOptions:response.data
            })
            console.log(this.state.filteredOptions)
         }
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        alert("Your Session time expired.Please Login Again."+error);
        this.props.history.push('/');   --> Redirect Working
     });

 e.preventDefault();
}
handleClick = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    var guid= localStorage.getItem('Guiid');
    console.log(guid);
  //  this.props.history.push('/')
    this.props.history.push('/Profile/'+guid);--> Redirect Not Working

}
routeChange() {
    var guid= localStorage.getItem('Guiid');
    this.props.history.push('/Profile/'+guid);--> Redirect Not Working

  }
  Redirect(){
    var guid= localStorage.getItem('Guiid');
    this.props.history.push('/dashboard/'+guid);--> Redirect Not Working

  }
  Follow(e,guid){
    this.props.history.push('/follow/'+guid);--> Redirect Not Working
  }
  Clear(){
    this.setState({ Search: ''})
    window.location.reload();
  }
  Follows(e,guid){
  //const history = useHistory();
    console.log(guid)
    var id= localStorage.getItem('Guiid');   
    if(guid==id)
    {           
     //history.push('/follow/'+guid) --> Redirect Not Working;
      this.props.history.push('/follow/'+guid);--> Redirect Not Working
    }else{
     //history.push('/follow/'+id) --> Redirect Not Working;
      this.props.history.push('/follow/'+id);--> Redirect Not Working
    }

 }

render() {

    return (


        <nav className="NXc7H jLuN9">
            <div className="XajnB"></div>
            <div>
                <div className="_8MQSO  Cx7Bp">
                    <div className="_lz6s  ">
                        <div className="MWDvN  ">
                            <div className="oJZym">
                                <a href='' onClick={() => this.Redirect()}>
                                    <div className="   Igw0E   rBNOH    eGOV_   ybXk5    _4EzTm   ">

                                        <div className="SvO5t"></div>
                                        <div className="cq2ai">
                                            <img alt="" className="s4Iyt" src={Logo} />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div className="LWmhU _0aCwM">
                                <input className="XTCLo x3qfX " type="text" autoCapitalize="none" placeholder="Search" value={this.state.Search} onChange={this.onChangeSearch} />
                                <span className="mlrQa coreSpriteSearchIcon sprite_search"></span>
                                {                  
                                     this.state.filteredOptions.map((user)=>{                    
                                  return (                       
                                   user.length != 0?
                                <div className="jLwSh" role="dialog"></div>
                                :null
                                )
                             })
                          }  
                                <div className="kbKz8">

                                 <div className="VR6_Q"></div>
                                  <div className="drKGC">
                                  {                  
                                     this.state.filteredOptions.map((user)=>{                    
                                  return (                       
                                   user.length != 0?
                                    <div className="fuqBx">
                                      <a className="yCE8d  " href="" onClick={(e) => this.Follows(e,user.User_Guiid)}>
                                       <div className="z556c">
                                         <div className="RR-M-  g9vPa" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                           <canvas className="CfWVH" height="42" width="42" style={{position: 'absolute', top: '-5px', left: '-5px', width: '42px', height: '42px'}}></canvas>
                                           <span className="_2dbep " role="link" tabindex="0" style={{width: '32px', height: '32px'}}>
                                           <img alt="" className="_6q-tv" src={require("../../img/Profile/"+user.UserImage)}/>
                                           </span>
                                          </div>
                                            <div className="_2_M76">
                                              <div className="uyeeR">
                                                 <span className="Ap253">{user.Username}</span>
                                                 <div className="JbY-k coreSpriteVerifiedBadgeSmall"></div></div>
                                                 <span className="Fy4o8">{user.Fullname}</span>
                                              </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                      :null
                                     )
                                  })
                               }  
                                </div>

                                </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
}
export default Header
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap you component in the **withRouter** HOC provided from the react-route-dom.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { history } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useHistory, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
....
....
..
export default withRouter(Header)
```

**withRouter** is a higher-order component that will pass the closest route's match, current location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders. simply it connects the component to the router.

Answer (score 2):

There is 2 way to call history push.

1. First one with HOC which is withRouter

So in the end you should wrap it. Then you can use push method like `this.props.history.push()`

```
export default withRouter(Header)
```

2. Second one is with help of Hooks. As I know you should use functionaly component to call hooks, so you should rewrite you code a little bit. I think this method a lot easier to write. You should import `import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'` then call it like `const history = useHistory()`. So you can call push method like `history.push()` and you not wrap your component with withRouter